# Godot Editors Debugger not getting updated

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

```
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_accept"):
        print("generating map")
        tempreture = generate_map(300, 5)
        moisture = generate_map(300, 5)
        altitude = generate_map(150, 5)
        set_tile()
        
func _process(delta):
        pass
```

ok, so i have this code here, the set_tile() function is a for loop with a million iterations, that is adding tiles at each pixel, when i trigger the event, i dont see print statement on the third line immedeitly, instead the set_tile() function finishes, and then i see the print statement, right as the screen gets updated with process function, any idea why this is? i asked in godot discord no one knows what might be the issue
also i tried adding a breakpoint at tempreture, and then it prints instantly on event trigger someone said that maybe editors debugger is not updating immedietly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i found a work around, run godot executable in terminal, the terminal works as a debugger, for godot project, it works flawless!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A running debug instance of your game connects to the editor via socket. When the game calls print it first buffers message data then sends it when appropriate from a background thread.

When the data reaches the editor the data is buffered again and passed to a logger processes the data then it eventually reaches godot's "console" node. The console node processes the data and then queues to later draw the actual message data as text.

When a breakpoint is triggered the print buffers are flushed immediately.

All this adds up to show that there is a bit of indeterminism in when the print message will display.

Comment: so far i figured out that it shows the message in debugger when the games frame is updated, i exported the project ran it via my linux terminal, and it shows the debug message perfectly, iam now trying to get an external editor to work with godot but failing miserably so far

Comment: I recommend sticking with the internal editor as you get a feel for godot. It's less hassle. If the docs on setting up an external editor aren't working for you try asking on discord or the official forum.

Comment: tried asking on discord, no help there, maybe i can try the forum, i wana stick to internal editor, but its just not working properly, maybe there is some setting i need to tweak, its still only updating the debugger when the game frame updates